# Manually remove TreeMap nested null values

Tags: java, json, gson, treemap

I am writing a method to remove manually null values from json (LinkedTreeMap).

```
    private static Gson gson = new Gson();

    public static LinkedTreeMap removeNullJsonObjects(Object object) {

        JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(object);
        LinkedTreeMap<Object, Object> linkedTreeMap = gson.fromJson(jsonElement, LinkedTreeMap.class);
        
        for (var entry : linkedTreeMap.entrySet()) {

            Object value = entry.getValue();
            if (value == null) {
                linkedTreeMap.remove(entry.getKey());
            } else if (value instanceof LinkedTreeMap<?, ?>) {
                removeNullJsonObjects(value);
                // here I need to loop again and save somehow result before ??
            }
        }

        return linkedTreeMap;
    }
```

But the problem is the depth of json can be 0...n. Which means I should loop N times and store it, I have no idea how to write the code for it.

So I can have json of any depth, for ex: like this:

```
{
    "technicalData": {
        "attributesList": {
            "attributes": [{
                    "attribute": {
                        "code": "LocalModelName",
                        "description": {
                            "value": "Boer"
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    "attribute": {
                        "code": "C303"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "modelGroups": {
        "modelGroup": [{}
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some problems in your implementation:

1. `linkedTreeMap.remove` inside for loop may cause `ConcurrentModificationException`
2. When the value is List, we should also check if its element is Map, and remove null value entry accordingly.
3. The remove logic should be extracted to a method, there is no need to convert the `Map` to `JsonElement` again.

Below code run on Java 16.

```java
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class RemoveNull {

    private static Gson gson = new Gson();
    private static String json =
            """
                    {
                        "technicalData": {
                            "attributesListNull": null,
                            "attributesList": {
                                "attributes": [{
                                        "attributeNull": null,
                                        "attribute": {
                                            "code": "LocalModelName",
                                            "description": {
                                                "value": "Boer",
                                                "valueNull": null
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }, {
                                        "attribute": {
                                            "code": "C303",
                                            "codeNull": null
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "modelGroups": {
                            "modelGroup": [{}],
                            "modelGroupNull": null
                        }
                    }
                    """;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JsonElement jsonElement = gson.fromJson(json, JsonElement.class);
        LinkedTreeMap<Object, Object> linkedTreeMap = gson.fromJson(jsonElement, LinkedTreeMap.class);
        System.out.println("Before remove:" + linkedTreeMap);
        removeNullMapping(linkedTreeMap);
        System.out.println("After remove:" + linkedTreeMap);
    }

    // Recursively remove null value mapping of input map, values of input map
    // and element in list values of input map
    private static void removeNullMapping(Map<Object, Object> map) {
        Iterator<Map.Entry<Object, Object>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            var entry = iterator.next();
            Object value = entry.getValue();
            if (value == null) {
                iterator.remove();
            } else if (value instanceof Map) {
                removeNullMapping((Map<Object, Object>) value);
            } else if (value instanceof List) {
                for (Object o : (List<Object>) value) {
                    if (o instanceof Map) {
                        removeNullMapping((Map<Object, Object>) o);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```